# How to access Vue $refs in a plugin?

Tags: vue.js, quasar

```js
methods: {  
  async create () {
    this.disableSubmit = true;
    await this.$firestore
      .collection('collectionName')
      .add(this.item)
      .then(() => {
        this.$refs.createForm.reset();
        this.$notify('positive', 'Item successfully created!');
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.$notify('negative', 'ERROR! Try again later!', error);
      });
    this.disableSubmit = false;
  },
}
```

If I use the code above inside the methods property, then everything works fine, but I would like to access that ref from outside the Vue component, for example a plugin, but it gives me an error.

> TypeError: "_this.$refs is undefined"

Even when I just import it as a function, the error is the same, so I would like to know how to access the ref outside `vue`?

Bellow is the code for my plugin, and I would also like to point that I am using the quasar framework.

```js
export let plugin = {
  install (Vue, options) {
    Vue.prototype.$plugin = async (collection, item) => {
      return await firestore
        .collection(collection)
        .add(item)
        .then(() => {
          this.$refs.createFrom.reset();
          notify('positive', 'Booking successfully created!');
        })
        .catch(error => {
          notify('negative', 'ERROR creating booking! Try again later!', error);
        });
    };
  }
};
```

I hope my question makes sense, and thanks in advance for any help

Comment: It would seem that, based on the plugin functionality, what you actually want is a mixin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could pass the context of your component, to apply the reset form from your plugin:

```
// plugin declaration
Vue.prototype.$plugin = async (collection, item, ctx) {
...
ctx.$refs.createFrom.reset()
...
}
```

then when u call to your plugin from yours components can do it like this:

```
// your component
methods: {
  myFunction () {
    this.$plugin(collection, item, this)
  }
}
```

`this` is the reference of the context of your current component that will be used inside of your plugin

for example:

```js
Vue.component('my-form', {
  methods: {
    resetForm() {
      console.log('the form has been reset')
    }
  }
})

Vue.prototype.$plugin = (item, ctx) => {
  console.log('item passed:', item)
  ctx.$refs.refToMyForm.resetForm()
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    item: 'foo'
  },  
  methods: {
    submit() {
      this.$plugin(this.item, this)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <my-form ref="refToMyForm"></my-form>
  <button @click="submit">submit</button>
</div>
```